# Google Kickstart 2020 Problem Record Breaker Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I was practising this problem asked in the last round of Google Kick Start 2020. The problem is called Record Breaker and is as follows:

> Isyana is given the number of visitors at her local theme park on N
> consecutive days. The number of visitors on the i-th day is Vi. A day
> is record breaking if it satisfies both of the following conditions:
> The number of visitors on the day is strictly larger than the number
> of visitors on each of the previous days. Either it is the last day,
> or the number of visitors on the day is strictly larger than the
> number of visitors on the following day. Note that the very first day
> could be a record breaking day!
>
> Please help Isyana find out the number of record breaking days.
>
> Input The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T
> test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the
> integer N. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is
> Vi.
>
> Output For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y,
> where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number
> of record breaking days.
>
> Limits Time limit: 20 seconds per test set. Memory limit: 1GB. 1 ≤ T ≤
> 100. 0 ≤ Vi ≤ 2 × 105.
>
> Test set 1 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000.
>
> Test set 2 1 ≤ N ≤ 2 × 105 for at most 10 test cases. For the
> remaining cases, 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000.
>
> Sample
>
> Input 4    8 1 2 0 7 2 0 2 0 6 4 8 15 16 23 42 9 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 6 9 9
> 9 9 9 9
>
> Output Case #1: 2 Case #2: 1 Case #3: 3 Case #4: 0
>
> In Sample Case #1, the bold and underlined numbers in the following
> represent the record breaking days: 1 2 0 7 2 0 2 0.
>
> In Sample Case #2, only the last day is a record breaking day.
>
> In Sample Case #3, the first, the third, and the sixth days are record
> breaking days.
>
> In Sample Case #4, there is no record breaking day.

This is the solution I created. It gives a Wrong Answer in the first Test Case but I can't think of any specific case that I have missed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int record_breaking(long long int arr[], long long int n)
{
    long long int ans = 0;
    long long int m = arr[0];
    for(long long int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //For first element
        if(i == 0 && arr[0] > arr[1])
        {
               ans++;
        }
        
        //For the last element
        else if(i == n - 1 && arr[i] > m)
        {
                ans++;
                //cout<<arr[i]<<" is a answer "<<endl;
               
        }
        //Normal Case
        else if(arr[i] > m && arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        {
                ans++;
                //cout<<arr[i]<<" is a answer "<<endl;
        }
        m = max(arr[i], m);
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int test = 1; test <= t; test++)
    {
        long long int n;
        cin>>n;
        long long int arr[200000];
        //int *arr = new int [n];
        for(long long int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Case #"<<test<<": "<<record_breaking(arr, n);
        //delete [] arr;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me figure out the problem with my solution!

Comment: `long long int arr[200000];` is not going to work everywhere. Use a `std::vector` if you don't know the size.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried, still it gives me a wrong answer. Here is the modified code [link](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/291782)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pass...

**Edge Case:**

**Input:**

1

1

2

**Output:**

1

but your code is giving 0 as an output...

What's wrong:

You are adding first if statement as (i == 0 && arr[0]>arr[1]) but there is no more than one element... So here first you have to check for this condition (i == n-1 && arr[i] > m)... That means you have to make correct order...

Also, initialize m = -1  Crucial for above edge case...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int record_breaking(vector<int> arr, int n)
{
    int ans = 0;
    int m = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        
        //For the last element
        if(i == n - 1 && arr[i] > m)
        {
                ans++;
                //cout<<arr[i]<<" is a answer "<<endl;
               
        }

        //For first element
        else if(i == 0 && arr[0] > arr[1])
        {
               ans++;
        }

        //Normal Case
        else if(arr[i] > m && arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        {
                ans++;
                //cout<<arr[i]<<" is a answer "<<endl;
        }
        m = max(arr[i], m);
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int test = 1; test <= t; test++)
    {
        int n, temp;
        cin>>n;
        vector<int> arr;
        //long long int arr[200000];
        //int *arr = new int [n];
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin>>temp;
            arr.push_back(temp);
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Case #"<<test<<": "<<record_breaking(arr, n);
        //delete [] arr;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup it did work. But what was wrong in initializing m as arr[0] ?